# How to configure PostgreSQL server on MacOS 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to my postgres server from command line :

```
    $> psql
    psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
      Is the server running locally and accepting
         connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

And I'm trying to run the server :

```
    $>postgres
    postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
    You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the 
    PGDATA environment variable.
```

Can anyone point out for me how can I configure my server so it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. Actually Mac OS 10.8.5 has his own psql command. So it's a path issue. If you install postgres from MacPort, the system will always refer to the initial psql command.

I advice you to install postgres from brew as shown [here](http://russbrooks.com/2010/11/25/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x).

You'll have also redefine your PATH environment variable and export it in your .profile file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```