# PostgreSQL: postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to configure postgreSQL as my local development database.

when I run

```
brew install postgres
```

I get the following error:

```
 postgresql-9.3.5 already installed
```

In my Gemfile I have the pg in the gem list.

When I run

```
rake db:create:all
```

I get the following error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

My database.yml looks like the following:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: fls_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  port: 5432

# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: fls_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
```

also, similar to this post: [How to configure PostgresSQL server on MacOS 10.8.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379415/how-to-configure-postgressql-server-on-macos-10-8-5), I get the following error when I just typ `postgres`

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

I am confused because the solution to the aforementioned SO post recommends installing with Homebrew however I am pretty sure that is how I installed it.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this same issue before and have fixed it by doing this

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
```

Answer (score 2):

so, this is a sort of indirect solution, but I simply ran `brew uninstall postgresql` and then installed the PostgreSQL app which runs automatically on the right port 5432.

Comment: id rather get the answer to your original question